# Is this clear overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, validation, overfitting

[image: Accuracy vs Epochs]

The orange curve is train accuracy and blue is validation accuracy. Is this clear overfitting or should I let it run for more epochs?

With custom dataset (1D data with 70 features) I trained a 2 layer MLP. 
Network Architecture: [70-200-200-4].
I'm only able to reach ~50+% accuracy. Any suggestions on what steps I can take to improve accuracy? (Obtaining more data isn't an option)

Answer (score 3):

> Is this clear overfitting or should I let it run for more epochs?

Yes that is overfitting

> With custom dataset (1D data with 70 features) I trained a 2 layer MLP. Network Architecture: [70-200-200-4]. I'm only able to reach ~50+% accuracy. Any suggestions on what steps I can take to improve accuracy? (Obtaining more data isn't an option)

what is the training dataset size? In my experience 2 hidden layered MLP is usually not needed, and when it is not needed and still employed, it ends up harming performance. Try making it less deep and more wide. As wide as your processors allow and counter the excess size with dropout.

Comment: There are nearly 145000 training samples. Thanks for your advice, will try a one layer network

Comment: that is not a big enough dataset to require so many layers. You might even want to include GBMs in your ensemble. For this small dataset, they work really good unless the data is something deep learning is very good at, like images

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it satisfactory

Comment: Thanks! I'm experimenting your suggestion. What would you suggest for improving train accuracy? Its not improving beyond 55-56%

Comment: train accuracy or val accuracy?

Comment: train accuracy stops improving beyond 55% and validation accuracy stops improving beyond 52-53%

Comment: Is this for regression or classification? Describe your final layer. What is the accuracy measure?

Comment: Its a classification problem. Final layer is cross entropy loss layer and accuracy measure is number of correct classifications. There is class imbalance -- I'm not looking at ROC or F-score yet simply because accuracy measure isn't anywhere close to good

Comment: try using 70-1000-4(logits) -4(softmax)-(cross entropy loss) without regularization and see if you exceed the train accuracy beyond what you are getting. For a given batch, use loss(minoroty class) = (#majorityclass/#minorityclass)*loss(majority class). basically send back higher gradient for minority class. double check gradients going back to 4 logits output. i have made mistakes in this in past

Comment: you should be able to always increase train accuracy with increasing the neurons. even if you are at 99% accuracy. you should be able to overfit the data to complete 100% accuracy if you kept increasing the number of neurons. So a problem in train accuracy is mostly a problem in your implementation

Comment: What does it mean if I'm unable to overfit on my trainset?

Comment: get accuracy on trainset that is abnormally high than the accuracy on val set. As i mentioned earlier, if you keep increasing number of neurons in hidden layer, you will fit any dataset. That does not mean you have learned something magical in your network. That means your network is overfitting and your validation accuracy wont be anywhere near

Comment: btw, your training accuracy will keep increasing beyond epoch 200 according to your curve

Comment: Yes, I understand that train accuracy should reach nearly 100% with a large enough network. But I'm beginning to doubt if that will happen with the dataset I've at hand (I don't know anything about the _quality_ of the data I am working with). Hence, I'm worried that the network will not overfit on trainset.

Comment: you can generate random numbers and network will fit even that. It does not matter what is the quality of the data is as long as they are preprocessed to a neural networks needs. (centered and standardized)

Comment: I didn't know NNs could even learn random numbers. And yes, [70 6000 4] network is overfitting, very slow though. Its reached a train accuracy of 78% after 2400 epochs.

Comment: NNs couldnt learn random numbers. They can overfit them. They can overfit anything

Comment: For speeding up training. Are you using 1. He initializations, 2. Adam optimizer, 3. batchnorm (use right after data input layer as well, to standardize the data)